# OpsCenter 5.0: Unable to get definition for cassandra-yaml for cluster settings

Tags: opscenter

Adding a cluster in OpsCenter 5.0 without problems. As far as I can see, there are no errors in opscenterd.log. However, the web interface doesn't show any nodes. I can see that all XHR calls in the browser look good though.

If I try to click "Cluster Actions" -> "Configure", I get this:

`Error
Unable to get definition for cassandra-yaml for cluster settings.`

I've tried re-installing OpsCenter (as well as dropping the OpsCenter keyspace), without any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is awkward. It turned out to be BitDefender Endpoint Security that blocked something. After adding our internal IPs to the "Traffic Scan Exclusions" in the policy, all seems fine.